# Copy files with changing filename

Tags: matlab, copy, filepath

I'm trying to copy several files with changing filenames. It seems very easy but I can't seem to work out how to do it without actually listing out the filenames in their entirety. The first few letters of the filenames correspond to the subject names which I'm looping through one by one. In each folder, there are 2 files, one is something like this `subj1_load1_vs_load2.img`, one is `subj1_load1_vs_load2.hdr`. I want both of them copied. Below is what I have:

```
subj={'subj1','subj2','subj3','subj4','subj5'}

for i=1:length(subj)
    source=fullfile(filedir,subj{i},sprintf('^%s_.*\.*',subj{i})); % this doesn't seem to work
    destination=fullfile(destdir,subj{i});
    copyfile(source,destination);
end
```

I've also tried:

```
source=dir([filedir subj{i} strcat(subj{i},'*')]);
```

This appears to needlessly complicate since I will need to deal with `.name`. But perhaps I don't know how to use this well.

Anyway, the problem is with `source` as I'm trying to find the files i want to copy.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, but there is definitely a `fullfile` missing in the last code line using `dir`. This way you just concatenate the file names without \

Comment: I've edited my question a bit to make it clearer. Basically I'm having trouble finding the files I want to copy. Also, I didn't get an error with the 'dir` line.

Comment: Did you take a look at the input you send to dir? Just the `[filedir subj{i} strcat(subj{i},'*')]`? I think it should be `fullfile(filedir,subj{i},strcat(subj{i},'*'))`

Comment: Oh yes, that works! Thank you!

Comment: @A.Rainer instead of placing *SOLVED* at the beginning of your question... which looks rather innocuous... place a separate answer detailing how you did it.

Comment: Happy to make the post clearer. I've added an answer (credit goes to Daniel) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is Daniel's answer (which solved the issue for me)

```
source=fullfile(filedir,subj{i},strcat(subj{i},'*'))
```